# how to round a number in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, rounding, truncate

I want if it is bigger or equal to 0 to round it to the bigger number and if it is smaller than 0 to round it to the number before. Eg: If the number is 2.5 show 3 and if the number is -2.5 show -3. How should i write this?
I wrote :

```
let round x = if (x >= 0) then int_of_float x
  else int_of_float ( x -. 1.0);;
```

or

```
let round x = if ( x>=0) then truncate (x +. 0.5) 
  else truncate ( x -. 0.5);;
```

and to both it gives me the same error :

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         float
```

How should I write it?

Comment: Years later, someone stumbled over it ^ ^ The error message comes from comparing to `0` instead of `0.0` or `0.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because `0` is a constant of type `int`. It will work better if you use `0.0`.

Personally I use this definition:

```
let frnd f = floor (f +. 0.5)
```

However, it doesn't work exactly like you want:

```
# frnd 2.5;;
- : float = 3.
# frnd (-2.5);;
- : float = -2.
# frnd (-2.500000001);;
- : float = -3.
```

I.e., it rounds up (toward positive infinity) values halfway between integers.

Answer (score 3):

Since 4.08.0, `round` is defined in the `Float` module

```
# Float.round 2.5
- : float = 3.
# Float.round 2.4
- : float = 2.
```